# Comparing files on the unix command line

Tags: unix, command-line, file

Suppose I have two files, A and B, and that lengthOf(A) < lengthOf(B). Is there a unix utility to tell if file B duplicates file A for the first lengthOf(A) bytes?

If I do "diff A B", the output will be all the 'extra stuff' in the B file, which misses the point; I don't care what else might be in file B.

If I do "comm A B", then I have to visually inspect that nothing turns up in the column for 'only in A'. This can be difficult when lengthOf(B) >> lengthOf(A), though I suppose it could be tamed with grep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems much better than creating temporary file:

```
SIZE=`stat -c %s filea`
cmp -s -n $SIZE filea fileb # -s for silence
```

Check the exit status to see whether the first bytes of those files are indeed equal.

Update: as per request of xk0der, here is a longer example:

```
wormhole:tmp admp$ echo -n "fooa" > one # -n to supress newline
wormhole:tmp admp$ echo -n "foobc" > two
wormhole:tmp admp$ SIZE=`stat -c %s one`
wormhole:tmp admp$ echo $SIZE
4
wormhole:tmp admp$ (cmp -s -n $SIZE one two && echo "equal") || echo "not equal"
not equal
wormhole:tmp admp$ echo -n "fooac" > two # first 4 bytes are equal now
wormhole:tmp admp$ (cmp -s -n $SIZE one two && echo "equal") || echo "not equal"
equal
```

Also, in MacOS X you have to use:

```
SIZE=`stat -f %z filename`
```

Comment: +1: nice one! Maybe you can add a line about how to test for exist status 'echo $?' or something :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `head -c` to specify the number of bytes for each file and then compare them.

I believe this requires creating at least one temporary file, but would appreciate any comments otherwise :)

Comment: You can use the '-' argument to diff.  This tells actually means "open stdin":  `head -c 100 a| diff - b`  This will compare the 1st 100 bytes in a to all of b.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe create a temporary file with the appropriate contents of b to the length of a?

Bit evil, but:

```
SIZE=`stat -c %s filea`
head -c$SIZE fileb >tempfile
diff filea tempfile
EXIT=$?
rm tempfile
exit $EXIT
```

Answer (score 1):

```
head -c`stat -c %s filea` fileb |diff -q filea -
```

Answer (score -2):

Write a custom awk script for it.